# Deleting a Parse user's Facebook authData

Tags: facebook, rest, authentication, parse-platform

A user of my app logged in using their Facebook account. They have since deleted their Facebook account so they are unable to log in.

I have tried to delete their Facebook authData using the REST API, however I don't have the user's Session Token. When I query the user in the Parse API Console it responds that the user doesn't have any active sessions.

I have applied a password to the account for the user to log in with their email address and password; I believe this will work if I am able to delete the Facebook authData.

How do I delete the user's authData so they can log back into their account and retain their profile?